# Why pandas is not installed in docker?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I use the pandas package from Alpine to build a docker image. But when I run python script, it said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`.

> FROM alpine:latest
>
> ADD crontab.txt /crontab.txt 
>   ADD  script.sh /script.sh 
>   COPY entry.sh
>   /entry.sh ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
>   COPY /centaline/scrapCentaline.py /scrapCentaline.py 
>   COPY /midland/scrapMidland.py /scrapMidland.py COPY torrc /etc/tor/torrc
>
> RUN chmod 755 /script.sh /entry.sh RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt
>
> RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >>
>   /etc/apk/repositories \ && apk update \ && apk add --no-cache python3
>   py-pip py3-setuptools python-dev py3-numpy py3-pandas
>
> RUN apk --update add --no-cache \  lapack-dev \  gcc \ freetype-dev \
>   tor \ torsocks
>
> RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \ gfortran \ musl-dev \
>   g++ RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
>
> RUN pip3 install aiohttp pymongo requests stem fake-useragent
>   aiohttp_socks
>
> EXPOSE 9050 EXPOSE 9051
>
> CMD ["/entry.sh"]

Comment: Even I do apk add py3-pandas in shell. The pandas is not installed.

Comment: Why not explicitly install `pandas` like `pip3 install pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would sincerely point you away from using the Alpine images if using pandas, as you will have to compile from libraries each time.

Here is a sample project which should work demonstrating how much easier your life will be using a slim-stretch build:

test_pandas.py:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('A'))
df.loc[0] = ['Hello']
print (df)
```

requirements.txt:

```
pandas==0.25.1
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY ./test_pandas.py /
CMD ["python", "/test_pandas.py"]
```

With these three files in the same directory run `docker build .`

```
Successfully built <image id>
```

Then run `docker run <image id>`

Result:

```
       A
0  Hello
```

Comment: thanks, the suggestion to not use alpine helped me a lot